# How Ubuntu Satanic Edition is different from regular Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, themes

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 Precise, and recently installed `ubuntu-satanic-edition`.

Here all I could find different is couple of themes and dozen of wallpapers? What something else there in it that I missed to notice? There has to be something important, special - what makes it possessed by Satans?

Indeed, 'tis an open-end question, but before it will be closed, I'm expecting some insight, at least in comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bunch of death metal themed packages, including music, screensavers, wallpaper and themes for Ubuntu and Kubuntu. You can [add their repo to a bog-standard version of Ubuntu](http://ubuntusatanic.org/installation.php) which is why I'm anwering this instead of closing it as off-topic :)

I have extracted the package name and description from [their Packages list](http://ubuntusatanic.org/hell/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages) and that should give you an idea of what's available.

```
Package: buuf-icon-theme
Description: The Buuf icon by Mattahan, packaged and tuned for GNOME.
 * Buuf - work by Mattahan, see http://mattahan.deviantart.com/

Package: eternal-damnation
Description: Eternity Screensaver Plugin - Ubuntu Satanic Edition
  Raytraced animations for the Eternity screensaver with an Ubuntu
  Satanic theme.

Package: eternal-studio
Description: Eternity Screensaver Plugin - Ubuntu Studio
  Raytraced animations for the Eternity screensaver with an Ubuntu Studio theme.

Package: eternal-ubuntu
Description: Eternity Screensaver Plugin - Ubuntu
  Raytraced animations for the Eternity screensaver with an Ubuntu theme.

Package: eternity-screensaver
Description: Eternity MPEG Screensaver
  Eternity is a screensaver which plays MPEG movies. It is intended to be
  used to play animtions generated by the POVray raytracer.

Package: gtk2-engines-aurora
Description: Aurora Gtk Engine
 The goal of this theme is to provide a complete and consistent look for Gtk.
 The theme aims to be very flexible in colour choice, but have few other options.
Original-Maintainer: Eric Matthews

Package: kubuntu-satanic
Description: Kubuntu Satanic Edition metapackage
 Installs all Ubuntu Satanic Edition components for Kubuntu/KDE
 Only 4:3 wallpapers are included

Package: kubuntu-satanic-wide
Description: Kubuntu Satanic Edition metapackage - widescreen
 Installs all Ubuntu Satanic Edition components for Kubuntu/KDE
 Only widescreen wallpapers are included

Package: music-for-the-damned
Description: Ubuntu Satanic Edition - Music for the Damned
 Compilation of creative commons licensed heavy metal music
 Artist: Various
 Album : Music for the Damned
 Genre : Metal
 Tracks: StabWounD - Death Assembly
         AUVERNIA - The Master Throne
         FRONTSIDE - Infantry
         Skaut - Overcome
         Taste of Hell - Rotten Inside
         Scape.Goat - Predator
         Holy Pain - The Ambassador Of Death

Package: satanic-gnome-themes
Description: Ubuntu Satanic Edition Gnome themes
 GTK 3 themes:
  * SatanicAdwaita - A dark theme based on Adwaita
  * SatanicAmbiance - A dark theme based on Ambiance
 GTK 2 themes:
  * Inhuman - a dark theme based on the Aurora Gtk engine
  * Inhuman Recant - a light theme based on the Aurora Gtk engine

Package: satanic-icon-themes
Description: Ubuntu Satanic Edition Icon themes
 * Sanguine - blood red icons based on Ubuntu Human
 * Revenge  - artistic icons based on the Buuf theme

Package: satanic-kde-themes
Description: Ubuntu Satanic Edition login and splash themes for KDE 4
 Contains:
  * Inferno, Glass, Skulls

Package: satanic-plymouth-theme
Description: Plymouth theme for Ubuntu Satanic Edition
 Plymouth theme for Ubuntu Satanic Edition

Package: satanic-sounds
Description: Ubuntu Satanic Edition GNOME audio theme
 Dark and foreboding sounds for the Gnome desktop

Package: satanic-wallpapers
Description: Ubuntu Satanic Edition desktop wallpapers
 Desktop wallpapers for Ubuntu Satanic Edition. Contains:
  * Satanic, Ice Nine, Hell, Pentagram,
  * 3D Glass (various renderings)
  * Bat, Baphomet, Diamondplate,
  * Inferno, Runes, Maelstrom,
  * Bathory, Bloodskulls, Skulls
  * Five Magics

Package: satanic-wallpapers-wide
Description: Ubuntu Satanic Edition desktop widescreen wallpapers
 Desktop wallpapers in 1680x1050 for Ubuntu Satanic Edition. Contains:
  * Satanic, Ice Nine, Hell, Pentagram,
  * 3D Glass (various renderings)
  * Bat, Baphomet, Diamondplate,
  * Inferno, Runes, Maelstrom,
  * Bathory, Bloodskulls, Skulls
  * Five Magics

Package: the-distro-of-the-beast
Description: Ubuntu Satanic Edition - The Distro of the Beast
 Compilation of creative commons licensed heavy metal music
 Artist: Various
 Album : The Distro of the Beast
 Genre : Metal
 Tracks: StabWounD - Shroudded In Darkness
         The Game - Mesentery
         Clenched Fists - Cynicism
         The Dog - Conchadors
         Different Way - Antarhes
         The Lake - Severed Fifth
         Until My Last Breath - Else
         Witch Hunting - Sirio
         Earth Crisis - Venesection
         Edge of Design - Severed Fifth
         Domination Through Amplification - Blueprint For Disaster

Package: ubuntu-satanic
Description: Ubuntu Satanic Edition metapackage
 Installs all Ubuntu Satanic Edition components for Ubuntu/Gnome
 Only 4:3 wallpapers are included

Package: ubuntu-satanic-wide
Description: Ubuntu Satanic Edition metapackage - widescreen
 Installs all Ubuntu Satanic Edition components for Ubuntu/Gnome
 Only widescreen wallpapers are included

Package: xinulive
Description: Ubuntu Satanic Edition - XinulivE
 Compilation of creative commons licensed heavy metal music
 Artist: Various
 Album : XinulivE
 Genre : Metal
 Tracks: Raise The Dead by Theorized
         TANK by T.A.N.K (Think of A New Kind)
         The Angel's Fall by Deathalizer
         Go To Hell by Lost World Order

Package: xubuntu-satanic
Description: Xubuntu Satanic Edition metapackage
 Installs all Ubuntu Satanic Edition components for Xubuntu/Xfce
 Only 4:3 wallpapers are included

Package: xubuntu-satanic-wide
Description: Kubuntu Satanic Edition metapackage - widescreen
 Installs all Ubuntu Satanic Edition components for Xubuntu/Xfce
 Only widescreen wallpapers are included
```

Comment: I was going by this [page](http://ubuntusatanic.org/quick-install.php), but all I've got is promised gtk3 themes `SatanicAdwaita` & `SatanicAmbiance` along with dozen of wallpapers, and no nothing of any aforesaid packages.I guess I shall be installing all packages separately to enjoy **Satanic Edition** for full

Comment: Well it's closed now. If you *really* want this to stay edit the question to be on-topic before reopening it please.